# Which heap is used while building project in eclipse?

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse

I am building a flex project manually in eclipse and want to know which heap is used during this process:

The heap used to run eclipse mentioned in eclipse.ini or the JRE heap specified within the eclipse?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the Flex Builder/Flash Builder plugins use the Java api to compile Flex apps, so they share the heap with Eclipse.  If you are running into slowness/OOM errors while compiling, try to set the heap higher in eclipse.ini.  You can also check the 'Show Heap Status' checkbox in the Eclipse preferences under the 'General' category. This will give you an indicator on the bottom-right corner of Eclipse showing used/total heap.